# gettings values from checkbox group with jQuery only works once

Tags: jquery, html, select, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to build an Array of the values of all selected checkboxes in a group (I have more than one checkbox group on this page, but below is one of them).

When I click on a checkbox I first get an alert with value of '0' and then an alert with value of '1'. This is as expected.
However, when I check a 2nd checkbox the alert no longer shows up. I also don't see any errors in my Chrome console.

Why?

**HTML**

```
    <table id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures" class="cblist textbox" style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$0\',\'\')', 0)" value="6">
                <label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_0">Arbor</label></td>
                <td><input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$4" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$4\',\'\')', 0)" value="7"><label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_4">Disabled access</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$1\',\'\')', 0)" value="3"><label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_1">Beach</label></td>
                <td><input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$5" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$5\',\'\')', 0)" value="4"><label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_5">Forest</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$2" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$2\',\'\')', 0)" value="1"><label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_2">Bridal suite</label></td>
                <td><input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$6" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$6\',\'\')', 0)" value="2"><label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_6">Garden</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$3" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$3\',\'\')', 0)" value="5"><label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_3">Dancing room</label></td>
                <td><input id="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_7" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$7" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$CPHCenter$cblFeatures$7\',\'\')', 0)" value="8"><label for="CPHCenter_cblFeatures_7">Water</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
     function getresults() {           
         var arr = new Array();
         $.each($("input[name*='cblFeatures']:checked"), function () {
             arr.push($(this).val());
         });

         alert(arr.length);
         arr = new Array();
         return true;
     }



     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#<%=cblFeatures.ClientID%>").click(function () { getresults(); });
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like it may be a problem with the `#<%=cblFeatures.ClientID%>`selector... Perhaps try something to this effect:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $("input[name*='cblFeatures']").click(function() { getresults(); });
 });
```

Here is a fiddle of it functioning the way you intended: http://jsfiddle.net/tcQwd/

Hope that helps!

Comment: It now works...it may have been that I had AutoPostBack=true on the asp.net checkboxlist control and placed everything in an updatepanel. I remove the autopostback and the updatepanel and that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define a `class` for your `checkboxes` and use that for `click` event as `id` is an unique attribute and click event using the `id` will only work for that particular `checkbox`. Assuming you have applied `checkbox` class to each of the checkbox than you can do it as follows

```
$(".checkbox").click(function () { getresults(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only assigning the click event to one id.

```
$("#<%=cblFeatures.ClientID%>").click(function () { getresults(); });
```